# JQuery property evaluation not working as expected

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm attempting to monitor changes to an existing checkbox in a form, and echo a specific message based on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="form_for_debugging" action='#' method='POST'>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name='input_number' value="111" maxlength="6" placeholder="#">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name='cb_field' id='cb_field' value='1'  > Check Me
    </form>

    <script>
        $('#cb_field').change(function() 
        {
            alert('change in cb_field detected...');
            if ($('cb_field').prop('checked')) 
            {
                alert('cb_field IS checked!');
            } else {
                alert('cb_field is NOT checked!');
            }

        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The issue is that the if statement returns false (`cb_field is NOT checked`) whether the checkbox is actually checked or not.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vf9tp5z7/)

Am I using the wrong property to test for this or am I missing something else important?

Comment: `$('cb_field')` is not the right selector

Comment: @CertainPerformance care to elaborate?  Should the selector address the form id instead?

Comment: It will try to select an element with a tag name of `cb_field` - which of course doesn't exist

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  There is a name property for the checkbox of 'cb_field'.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp says "The jQuery #id selector uses the id attribute of an HTML tag to find the specific element." so why wouldn't my example work

Comment: Because you forgot the `#`

Comment: If you'd like internet points pls post an answer and I'll hook you up

Comment: The question is closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56074659 - the problem boils down to misunderstanding of selectors (or a typo)